# Looking for a way to find the differential equation of an orthogonal regression

Tags: r, regression, poly

I used orthogornal regression in R to find a relation between two variables. I I want to find the tangent in several points on the best fit line.

```
D(expression (model), "x")
```

gives me a very unexpected result. I suspect it is because the poly function uses orthogornal polynomiums. In the regression above i get

```
D(expression(44+ 67*x -5.5*x^2), "x")
```

which returns me

```
67 - 5.5 * (2 * x)
```

It is obviously wrong,  "like the coefficients" (know they are not wrong).

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y <-c(10,15,23,33,46,50,57,63,68,75)
model <- lm( y ~poly(x,2))
```

Now i want to find the tangent in x=2 and  x=7

If i just look at the numbers i suspect that in x=2 the tangent would be something like 6.5? (23-10) / (3-1)

Because it is a second order poly regression, it it makes no sense to input the summary variables i get from the regression, as it gives a meaningless result

Comment: Have you tried with an ordinary least squared regression for comparison?

Comment: `poly` gives _orthogonalized_ polynomial points, which means that the _basis_ has been changed. You might try linear transformation for x=2 and x=7 if you want their slope at those points.